# QT_STATIC_CONST does not name a type

Tags: qt, ubuntu, qwt

I was using QT5.4.1 version with the QWT-6.1.2 library that I've installed but in compiling I receive the error "QT_STATIC_CONST does not name a type". After some researsh how to fix that, I found that I should install the QT version 5.5.
I have that already achieved but the error appears although!
I use Kubuntu by the way
What should I do ?

Comment: The fix is not to install Qt 5.5 but to upgrade Qwt. Are you sure it's QWT-6.1.2 and not QWT-6.1.1 ? What is your Kubuntu version ?

Comment: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/qwt-qt5/+bug/1485213

Answer (score 2):

QT_STATIC_CONST’ does not name a type.
By defining QT_STATIC_CONST just before inserting Qwt file, compilation works.
- In Qt5.4 , QT_STATIC_CONST was removed from qglobal.h
- Qwt 6.1.1 uses this macro, but fixed it in Qwt 6.1.2

Answer (score 0):

Here is the content that was removed from qglobal.h that created this issue. Adding this to your code prior to including the header file should resolve the issue.

```
/*
   Workaround for static const members on MSVC++.
*/

#if defined(Q_CC_MSVC)
#  define QT_STATIC_CONST static
#  define QT_STATIC_CONST_IMPL
#else
#  define QT_STATIC_CONST static const
#  define QT_STATIC_CONST_IMPL const
#endif
```